# Arithmetics operation with item with ansible

Tags: ansible

I would like to add each item in a loop.

For example :

**Variables:**

```
FS:
    - nom_FS: /apps/oracle/{{ SID | lower }}/syst01
      nom_LV: "lv{{ TRIGRAMME | lower }}syst01"
      size_FS: 20
      owner_FS: oracle
      group_FS: dba
      vg_name: vgdata

    - nom_FS: /apps/oracle/{{ SID | lower }}/syst02
      nom_LV: "lv{{ TRIGRAMME | lower }}syst02"
      size_FS: 20
      owner_FS: oracle
      group_FS: dba
      vg_name: vgdata
```

**Playbook:**

```
- name: size FS
  shell: /bin/echo "({{item.size_FS.0}}+{{item.item.size_FS.1}})" | bc
  register: check_size_disk
  with_items: "{{ FS }}"
```

I tried other things without success...

Could you help me please ?

Comment: if you don't  have 1000 filesystems you can use with_dict

Comment: That is the problem, I have a lot of filesystems but it is curious that we can't select only the item desired

Answer (score 4):

Simple addition should work

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ size_FS1 + size_FS2 }}"
```

To be sure the strings will be converted use [int](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#int) filter.

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ size_FS1|int + size_FS2|int }}"
```

To add each item in a loop simple addition works too

```
- set_fact:
    sum: "{{ sum|default(0)|int + item|int }}"
  loop: "{{ FS|json_query('[].size_FS') }}"
```

The simplest option is to use the [sum](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#sum) filter.

```
- set_fact:
   sum: "{{ FS|map(attribute='size_FS')|list|sum }}"
```

Comment: Not because it is a dict, and so the item has the same name. I have to play with an index : FS:
    - nom_FS: /apps/oracle/{{ SID | lower }}/syst01
      nom_LV: "lv{{ TRIGRAMME | lower }}syst01"
      size_FS: 20
      owner_FS: oracle
      group_FS: dba
      vg_name: vgdata

    - nom_FS: /apps/oracle/{{ SID | lower }}/syst02
      nom_LV: "lv{{ TRIGRAMME | lower }}syst02"
      size_FS: 20

Comment: I've added the loop into the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I will check tomorrow !! Thanks !

Comment: @pnakache If this is fulfilling your requirements, you should accept the answer to let the other users know a solution was found.